# EInvalidCast wih mock function returning a pointer type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti, delphi-mocks

I've written an interface to wrap the Windows Threadpool API and many of those functions return plain `Pointer` types.

Now I'm writing tests and want to use the [delphi-mocks framework](https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/Delphi-Mocks) to mock that wrapper interface.

The problem is that the `TMock` setup interface takes a `TValue` object to specify a default return value for the mocked functions and I can't see a way how to do that correctly from the available [`TValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TValue_Methods) functions. Though I've seen that `ekPointer` is a valid [`TTypeKind`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TypInfo.TTypeKind) value.

When the mocked function is called I receive an `EInvalidCast` exception from the corresponding RTTI invocation.
That happens specifically, when the RTTI invocation tries to cast the return type value from the implicit `TValue` object.

My code looks roughly like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
type
    PTP_POOL = Pointer;
    PTP_CLEANUP_GROUP = Pointer;

    IThreadPoolApi = interface(IInterface)
        {...}
        function CreateThreadPool() : PTP_POOL;
        function CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup() : PTP_CLEANUP_GROUP;
        {...}
    end;
```

the class under test

```
type
    TThreadPool = class(TInterfacedObject, IThreadPool)
        FTPApi : IThreadPoolApi;
        FPTPPool : PTP_POOL;
        FPTPCleanupGroup : PTP_CLEANUP_GROUP;
        {...}
    public
        constructor Create(iapi : IThreadPoolApi);
    end;

implementation
constructor TThreadPool.Create(iapi : IThreadPoolApi);
begin
    inherited Create();
    FTPApi := iapi;

    {**** Here I get a EInvalidCast exception when mocking the interface ****}
    FPTPPool := FTPApi.CreateThreadPool();
    if(not assigned(FPTPPool)) then
    begin
        {Raise exception}
        raise EThreadPoolError('Cannot create TP thread pool');
    end;

    {**** This case should be tested ****}
    FPTPCleanupGroup := FTPApi.CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup();
    if(not assigned(FPTPPool)) then
    begin
         {Raise exception}
         raise EThreadPoolError('Cannot create TP cleanup group');
    end;

    {...}
end;
```

and the testing stuff

```
procedure ThreadPoolTest.TestFail_CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup();
var
   apiMock : TMock<IThreadPoolApi>;
   testproc : TTestLocalMethod;
begin
   apiMock := TMock<IThreadPoolApi>Create();
   {**** Needed to reach the call of CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup
    but EInvalidCast is raised ****}
   apiMock.Setup.WillReturnDefault('CreateThreadPool',PTP_POOL($FFFFFFFF));
   {**** The case to be tested ****}
   apiMock.Setup.WillExecute('CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup',
       function (const args : TArray<TValue>; const ReturnType : TRttiType) 
       : TValue
       begin
           result := nil;
       end);

    testproc := 
       procedure() 
       var
           threadpool : IThreadPool;
       begin
           threadpool := TThreadPool.Create(apiMock);
       end;
    DUnitX.Assert.WillRaise(testproc,EThreadPoolError,
                            'Cannot create TP cleanup group');
end;
```

**TL;DR;**

So the question is:
**What do I need to do that `TValue` is created properly to contain a `PTP_POOL` pointer type?**

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>It's a bit too much code to setup a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I just sketch it here to give you the background, see the `{**** highlighted comments ****}`</sub>

Comment: Regarding the DV. It's a bit hard to setup a MCVE for this question, but that's not in question anyway. Skip to the **TL;DR;** please. I pretty well know what's going on.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for exactly.  And you didn't show the implementation of `CreateThreadPool()` that is causing the problem.  On the other hand, `result := nil;` in your `WillExecute()` procedure should probably be `Result := TValue.From<Pointer>(nil);` instead. `TValue` does not have an implicit conversion for raw pointers, but it does have one for `TObject` pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau _"I don't understand what you are asking for exactly."_ I believe it's crystal clear. Just read the question in the end of the question. The `WillExecute() procedure` works well (I made it so, because using `WillReturnDefault()` with `nil` didn't work well). But your comment to create `TValue` with the `WillReturnDefault()` using `TValue.From<PTP_POOL>($FFFFFFFF);` probably answers my question. I'll test that tomorrow, when back at my desk.

Comment: You would have to use `TValue.From<PTP_POOL>(PTP_POOL($FFFFFFFF))` instead. You can't pass a hex literal where a pointer is expected unless you type-cast it, otherwise you get an error: `E2010 Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'Integer'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When assigning a raw pointer to a `TValue`, use the [`TValue.From<T>()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue.From) method, eg:

```
TValue.From<PTP_POOL>(nil);
```

Or, if you want to return a literal value:

```
TValue.From<PTP_POOL>(PTP_POOL(value));
```

`TValue` does not have an implicit conversion for raw pointers, but it does have implicit conversions for `TObject` and `TClass` pointers.

If you assign an untyped nil pointer directly to `TValue`, it calls `TValue.Implicit(TObject)`, which will return the `TValue.Empty` property when passed a nil pointer.

If you assign a typed non-`TObject` pointer directly to `TValue`, it calls `TValue.Implicit(TClass)`, which returns `TValue.Empty` if the pointer is nil, otherwise it returns a `TValue` of type `TClass` with the value of the pointer, even if it is not actually pointing at a valid class type.

If you pass a pointer to `TValue.From<T>()`, it returns a `TValue` of type `T` with the value of the pointer, even if it is nil.

This difference is subtle, but very important.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, the problematic part was the `WillReturnDefault()` function. But anyways, your answer seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that solves the problem. As mentioned, be a bit patient with me please ;-). Is that a dupe in the [tag:delphi] realm? There wasn't anything proposed when I composed that question.

Comment: _"This difference is subtle, but very important."_ Yes, subtle. When landing in the assembler code in debugging the `TryCast()` function, I was a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

> **What do I need to do that `TValue` is created properly to contain a `PTP_POOL` pointer type?**

It looks like @Remy already answered my question in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433385/einvalidcast-wih-mock-function-returning-a-pointer-type#comment79824796_46433385).

To have that pointer value contained in a `TValue` instance it must be created using the generic [`TValue.From<T>()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue.From) function:

```
apiMock.Setup.WillReturnDefault('CreateThreadPool',
                                TValue.From<PTP_POOL>(PTP_POOL($FFFFFFFF)));
```

and a bit of casting.

Comment: You should do the same in your `WillExecute()` function. `result := nil` does not return what you think it will. Use `Result := TValue.From<PTP_POOL>(nil)` instead.

Comment: @Remy That worked well with the `TMock` implementation though, when I was about testing the `CreateThreadPool()` call with a `nil` result :-P. That was probably my main source of confusion, since neither of `WillExecute()` nor `WillReturnDefault()` worked when approaching my 2nd test case.

Comment: @Remy My latter hope  to replace the `WillExecute()` calls to return a `nil` value with `WillReturnDefault()` unfortunately didn't fulfill. The Delphi-Mocks framework doesn't accept `nil` values (typed or not) with `WillReturnDefault()`.